# How to change current page, switching from activity_main.xml to pagetwo.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, navigation

I can not move from one page to another.
The button does not work, if I press it nothing happens.
Can you explain why?
I'd simply like to go to page `activity_main.xml` to `pagetwo.xml`, and in order to do it I try to change `Activity`.

My pages:

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

     ...

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...

    }
}


class open extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                  Intent i= new Intent("call");
                  startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**call:**

```
public class call extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pagetwo);
    }
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
 ...
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".call"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action  android:name="android.intent.action.PICK_ACTIVITY"/>
            <category  android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**pagetwo:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Finally"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main:**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="page two" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Bye!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: Your code is way overly complicated and shows you don't understand activities (you shouldn't have more than 2 here, and shouldn't be mixing Activity and AppCompatActivity).  I suggest reading tutorials and docs, giving you the code to fix this would do you more harm than good.

Comment: thank you, i read all and now i solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change code like below and check

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
       button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
                  Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.class, call.class);
                  startActivity(i);
           }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the intent correctly. Please, check source code below for class `open`

```
class open extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
       button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
                  Intent i= new Intent(this, call.class);
                  startActivity(i);
           }
       });
    }
}
```